# Folder and file not added to User's Application Data folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, setup-project

Ladies and Gentlemen , I have been stuck with this for a few hours and do not find an answer. I have a Setup project in Visual Studio that creates an installer for my C# application. What I want is to add a folder with an XML file from which my application can read and write to the User's Application Data folder. In the File System Editor window I added the User's Application Data folder. In this folder I added a new folder (renaming it to my app's name) and then place the XML file in there. I also set the AlwaysCreate to true for the folder. The installer should create the folder in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local and add the file to it. However, the installer does not create the folder or the XML file my application uses. What am I missing? Is there another way to install a read/write XML file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And if you search for the File? The CompanyName\\ApName\\Version is ususally added.

Comment: Try creating an install log to see what happens with the file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I found what the issue was. If a file is added to the User's Application Data folder it is installed on the target computer at C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming and not into AppData\Local.

Therefore, I changed my application get the file from Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) instead of Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData).

Hope it helps someone else...

Comment: It Sure Did My Friend .. ^___^

Comment: If you really need AppData\Local, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50061307/267152